# How can I hide everything (including desktop icons) when I resume from sleep mode?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, desktop

Sometimes I need a "scratchpad" for creative ideas... and I reach for a pen and paper because I know that

1. The paper is blank
2. There are no notifications, sounds, or bouncing icons
3. I have an intention, and I want to follow through with that, with no distractions.

I'm stuck on how to make MacOS start that way, unless I leverage the guest mode.  For some reason that isn't working for me. Perhaps it's because the guest mode is not natural b/c I'm missing my apps, or a specific permissions (keychain password) relevant to my task is needed.

That being said, is there any way I can start from a clean slate when resuming from sleep mode?

Comment: For what it's worth, in iOS 11 the iPad Pro will work exactly like that: touch the tip of your Pencil to the iPad's lock screen, and a blank Note pops up, ready for you to write/draw on.

Comment: @Phong Yea! Something like that!  Maybe like if it did that if I immediately clicked or typed within .5 second of an unlock

Comment: I believe some apps exist that can run scripts on wake/unlock. Maybe someone can suggest one. I know you can't set that up under Automator.

Comment: What type of action is required? Uncluttered Desktop? One note taking app in fullscreen? A more graphical app? Should this action be always performed on every wake?